# Поймать нажатие на UIImageView при анимации

Tags: ios, swift4, uiimage

Всем привет! Не срабатывает нажатие на картинку во время её анимации.
Если я правильно понимаю, применяемый способ анимации двигает layer но не frame, который и реагирует на нажатие.

Есть ли варианты дополнить текущий код или другие варианты анимированного передвижения UIImageView так, чтобы касание срабатывало во время анимации?

Спасибо за помощь.

swift 4

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // action by tap
        let gestureSwift2AndHigher = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.actionUITapGestureRecognizer))
        myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureSwift2AndHigher)

    }

    // action by tap
    @objc func actionUITapGestureRecognizer (){

        print("actionUITapGestureRecognizer - works!") // !!! IT IS DOES NOT WORK !!!

    }

    // hide UIImageView before appear
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        myImageView.center.y += view.bounds.height

    }

    // show UIImageView after appear with animation
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.myImageView.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с рабочим тапом, ставит анимацию на паузу на первый этап, на второй запускает дальше. И советую посмотреть видео с WWDC 2017 [Advanced Animations with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/230/)

```
enum AnimationStatus {
    case paused
    case active
}

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    var myAnimation: UIViewPropertyAnimator!
    var animationStatus: AnimationStatus = .paused


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, curve: .linear) {
            UIView.setAnimationDelay(0)
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
            self.myImageView.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height
        }
        // action by tap
        let gestureSwift2AndHigher = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (actionUITapGestureRecognizer(sender:)))
        myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureSwift2AndHigher)

    }

    // action by tap
    @objc func actionUITapGestureRecognizer (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        switch self.animationStatus {
        case .active:
            self.myAnimation.pauseAnimation()
            self.animationStatus = .paused
        default:
            self.myAnimation.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: nil, durationFactor: 1)
            self.animationStatus = .active
        }

        print("actionUITapGestureRecognizer - works!") 

    }

    // hide UIImageView before appear
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        myImageView.center.y += view.bounds.height

    }

    // show UIImageView after appear with animation
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.myAnimation.startAnimation()
        self.animationStatus = .active
    }
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо за данное решение и за видео!